# Don't submit unless all data is entered

Tags: javascript, html, function, registration

I have a function for a registration page where if the data required isn't entered by the user then it alerts the user to fill it in. The form still submits the information though so not sure what I'm doing wrong. I want it to not submit until all data is submitted and correct.

```
function checkdetails()
{
    if (document.form1.txtname.value == "")
    {alert("Please fiill in your forename.");
    }
    if (document.form1.txtsurname.value == "")
    {alert("Please fill in your surname.");
    }
    if (document.form1.txtusername == "")
    {alert("Please create a username.");
    }
    if (document.form1.DOBDay.selectedIndex == 0)
    {alert("Please select the day you were born.");
    }
    if (document.form1.DOBMonth.selectedIndex == 0)
    { alert("Please select the month you were born");
    }
    if (document.form1.DOBYear.selectedIndex == 0)
    {alert("Please fill in the year you were born.");
    }
    if (document.form1.txtemail.value == "")
    {alert("Please enter your e-mail address.");
    }
    if (document.form1.terms.checked == false)
    {alert("Please tick that you have read the Terms and Conditions.");
    }
}
```

```
<form action="Home.html" method="post" name="form1" onsubmit="Display()">
  <table bgcolor="white" width="700" border="0" align="center">
  <col width="200">
  <col width="200">


    <tr>
    <th colspan = "2" align = "center" bgcolor="grey"> Fill the form to sign up. </th>
    </tr>
<tr>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    </tr>


    <tr>
    <td colspan="2" style="font-size:12px">Fields marked with * are mandatory</td>
    </tr>


    <tr>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    </tr>


    <tr>
      <td>Forename*</td>
      <td>Surname*</td>
    </tr>


    <tr>
      <td><label>
        <input type="text" name="txtname" id="txtname" class="info" />
      <td><label>
        <input type="text" name="txtsurname" id="txtsurname" class="info" />
      </label></td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
    <td> Create Username*</td>
    <td> Birthday</td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
    <td><label>
    <input type="text" name="txtusername" id="txtusername" class="info"/>
    </label></td>




    <td><select name="DOBMonth">
    <option>    Month  </option>
    <option value="January">January</option>
    <option value="Febuary">Febuary</option>
    <option value="March">March</option>
    <option value="April">April</option>
    <option value="May">May</option>
    <option value="June">June</option>
    <option value="July">July</option>
    <option value="August">August</option>
    <option value="September">September</option>
    <option value="October">October</option>
    <option value="November">November</option>
    <option value="December">December</option>
</select>

<select name="DOBDay">
    <option> Day </option>
    <option value="1">1</option>
    <option value="2">2</option>
    <option value="3">3</option>
    <option value="4">4</option>
    <option value="5">5</option>
    <option value="6">6</option>
    <option value="7">7</option>
    <option value="8">8</option>
    <option value="9">9</option>
    <option value="10">10</option>
    <option value="11">11</option>
    <option value="12">12</option>
    <option value="13">13</option>
    <option value="14">14</option>
    <option value="15">15</option>
    <option value="16">16</option>
    <option value="17">17</option>
    <option value="18">18</option>
    <option value="19">19</option>
    <option value="20">20</option>
    <option value="21">21</option>
    <option value="22">22</option>
    <option value="23">23</option>
    <option value="24">24</option>
    <option value="25">25</option>
    <option value="26">26</option>
    <option value="27">27</option>
    <option value="28">28</option>
    <option value="29">29</option>
    <option value="30">30</option>
    <option value="31">31</option>
</select>

<select name="DOBYear">
    <option> Year </option>
    <option value="2016">2016</option>
    <option value="2015">2015</option>
    <option value="2014">2014</option>
    <option value="2013">2013</option>
    <option value="2012">2012</option>
    <option value="2011">2011</option>
    <option value="2010">2010</option>
    <option value="2009">2009</option>
    <option value="2008">2008</option>
    <option value="2007">2007</option>
    <option value="2006">2006</option>
    <option value="2005">2005</option>
    <option value="2004">2004</option>
    <option value="2003">2003</option>
    <option value="2002">2002</option>
    <option value="2001">2001</option>
    <option value="2000">2000</option>
    <option value="1999">1998</option>
    <option value="1998">1998</option>
    <option value="1997">1997</option>
    <option value="1996">1996</option>
    <option value="1995">1995</option>
    <option value="1994">1994</option>
    <option value="1993">1993</option>
    <option value="1992">1992</option>
    <option value="1991">1991</option>
    <option value="1990">1990</option>
    <option value="1989">1989</option>
    <option value="1988">1988</option>
    <option value="1987">1987</option>
    <option value="1986">1986</option>
    <option value="1985">1985</option>
    <option value="1984">1984</option>
    <option value="1983">1983</option>
    <option value="1982">1982</option>
    <option value="1981">1981</option>
    <option value="1980">1980</option>
    <option value="1979">1979</option>
    <option value="1978">1978</option>
    <option value="1977">1977</option>
    <option value="1976">1976</option>
    <option value="1975">1975</option>
    <option value="1974">1974</option>
    <option value="1973">1973</option>
    <option value="1972">1972</option>
    <option value="1971">1971</option>
    <option value="1970">1970</option>
    <option value="1969">1969</option>
    <option value="1968">1968</option>
    <option value="1967">1967</option>
    <option value="1966">1966</option>
    <option value="1965">1965</option>
    <option value="1964">1964</option>
    <option value="1963">1963</option>
    <option value="1962">1962</option>
    <option value="1961">1961</option>
    <option value="1960">1960</option>
    <option value="1959">1959</option>
    <option value="1958">1958</option>
    <option value="1957">1957</option>
    <option value="1956">1956</option>
    <option value="1955">1955</option>
    <option value="1954">1954</option>
    <option value="1953">1953</option>
    <option value="1952">1952</option>
    <option value="1951">1951</option>
    <option value="1950">1950</option>
    <option value="1949">1949</option>
    <option value="1948">1948</option>
    <option value="1947">1947</option>
</select>




    <tr>
      <td>Email*</td>
      <td>Confirm Email*</td>
    </tr>


    <tr>
      <td><label>
        <input type="text" name="txtemail" id="txtemail" class="info" onchange="ValidateEmail(txtemail)" />
      <td><label>
        <input type="text" name="txtemail2" id="txtemail2" class="info" onchange="ValidateEmail2(txtemail2)"/>
      </label></td>
    </tr>


    <tr>
      <td>Password*</td>
      <td>Confirm Pasword*</td>
    </tr>


    <tr>
      <td><label>
        <input type="password" name="txtpassword" id="txtpassword" class="info"/>
      <td><label>
        <input type="password" name="txtpassword2" id="txtpassword2" class="info"/>
      </label></td>
    </tr>


    <td colspan="2" style="font-size:12px">**Passwords must be at least 8 characters in lenght.</td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    </tr>


      <tr>
      <td colspan="2">
        <label>
          <input type="checkbox" name="terms" value="terms" id="terms" />
          I agree to the Terms and Conditions</label>
        </td></tr>
        <br><br><br>
        <tr>
        <td colspan="2"><label>
          <input type="checkbox" name="notify" value="notify" id="notify" />
          I want to receive notifications by text/email about new products in stock.</label>
          </td>
    </tr>


    <tr>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    </tr>

     <tr>
    <td><label>
      <input type="submit" name="Login" id="Login" value="Login" onclick="checkdetails()" />
    </label></td>
    <td><label>
      <input type="reset" name="Reset" id="Reset" value="Reset" />
    </label></td>
  </tr>

    <tr>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</form>
```

Comment: use this for stop submit if there is error (  funcion validate(){
retur false;
}
$( "#yourform" ).submit(function( event ) {
 if(!validate())
  event.preventDefault();
}); )

Answer (score 3, accepted):

it's better to use html5 attribute required !

```
<input type="text" name="input" required >
```

Comment: Not all the browsers support the `required` attribute.

Comment: Never heard of this attribute in college I'm only new. It worked wonders thanks a million!

Answer (score 0):

return false; should prevent it from performing it's action.

```
<form name="testForm" onsubmit="return validate();"> 

<script type="text/javascript">
function validate()
{
  if(check if your conditions are not satisfying)
  { 
    alert("validation failed false");
    returnToPreviousPage();
    return false;
  }

  alert("validations passed");
  return true;
}
</script>
```

However, as stated in answer above, html5 required attribute is best practice. You will need to consider more than just empty fields though. For example, will need to regex check your email field, etc.

http://www.html5-tutorials.org/form-validation/validating-email/